# UNA CONSULTA HE GENERADO UNA MACRO EN EXCEL CON VISUAL BASIC

Tags: excel, vba, macros

He generado una macro en Excel con visual Basic

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:H")) Is Nothing Then

ActiveSheet.Unprotect "123456"

Target.Locked = True

ActiveSheet.Protect "123456"

End If

ActiveSheet.Unprotect "123456"

Application.MoveAfterReturn = False

If Target.Count = 1 Then

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:H")) Is Nothing Then

Cells(Target.Row, "k") = Now

End If

ActiveSheet.Protect "123456"

End Sub
```

El código funciona bien, pero al momento de compartirlo me genera un error 1004 alguna idea por favor.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Bienmvenido a SO en español. ¿qué línea da el error? Además, te falta un End IF en este código.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, el error mencionado es debido a que la macro se está copiando en una fila completa de excel o copia y pega un rango de 2.516 filas o más en un libro de Excel.

Para evitar este problema, la macro que copia y pega una fila completa debes cambiarle el código para copiar sólo la sección de la fila que contiene datos. Por ejemplo, utilice código de macro VBA que es similar al código siguiente:

```
Range(Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), Range("IV" & ActiveCell.Row).End(xlToLeft)).Select
```

Ante cualquier duda, consultar.

[Fuente:  Support Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/es-cl/help/905164/you-receive-a-runtime-error-1004-error-message-when-you-try-to-copy-an)

PD: A modo de recomendación explora las herramientas de formato de código y etiquetado para que tus preguntas estén mas claras y sean mas fáciles de responder.

Comment: el error me aparece cuando comparto el libro para que puedan modificar varios usuarios me aparece se ha producido un error 1004 en tiempo de ejecución: error en el método unprotect de la clase worksheet

Comment: Te recomiendo que añadas estos detalles en tu pregunta, dado que el error que tu especifica un error de memoria y el mas conocido es ese. Si puedes adjunta pantallazos del libro y del mismo error.